# How to create access Point in pc using java

Tags: java

I want to create an access point on the computer using Java, but all what I found on the Internet was not clear
I was trying to implement this solution. https://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/api/gcf/api/javax/microedition/io/AccessPoint.html
but I can't import this in my app
   import javax.microedition.io.AccessPoint;

Comment: javax.microedition was part of the J2ME distribution.

Comment: are can I use this library in desktop application?

Comment: Basically, no you can't.  Java ME is for certain (old) kinds of mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Java ME SDK.
Check this link: http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/01/02/j2me-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-midlet-application-with-netbeans/.

Comment: then are you know how can I create Acces Point in PC windows